# Retrieve any name starting with letters 'Ai' in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

All I want to do is retrieve the names of the people who start with "ma".

Eg Matt, Mathers, Mac.

First, two letters have to be 'ma'.

Comment: This post shows absolutely no research or effort on your part.

Comment: Case sensitive or not? I.e both ma, MA, Ma and mA?

Comment: Select FirstName From Table Where FirstName Like 'ma%'

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [string comparisons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  NAME LIKE 'MA%';
```

Comment: Not just first letter. First and second letter of name has to be in order 'ma...'

Comment: Just to increment the answer: MySQL LIKE use both Upper and Lowercase. So, LIKE 'A%' should return "Ana" or "ana"

Comment: "Just to increment the answer: MySQL LIKE use both Upper and Lowercase. So, LIKE 'A%' should return "Ana" or "ana"" @SauloGomes No that's not right it depends on the table collation or column collation

Comment: @RaymondNijland it depends if you are performing or not a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: @RaymondNijland and everyone that wants to understand it. We can see the example here < https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html >.
Something like this would return false:

SELECT 'abc' LIKE _latin1 'ABC' COLLATE latin1_general_cs;

But, something like this would return true:
SELECT 'abc' LIKE 'ABC';

Comment: Like i said McNets and @SauloGomes LIKE works on table collation or column collation see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25c06e/2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  NAME LIKE 'MA%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There can be spaces at the beginning of the name just like '  Matthew'. This would fix it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  ltrim(NAME) LIKE 'MA%'
```